# How to create a Python 3.8 virtual environment in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, virtualenv

In Ubuntu 16.04 the latest release of Python3 is 3.5. If I just do `virutalenv venv` it would create a new virtual environment using Python 3.5.

I followed the instructions in https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-8-on-ubuntu-18-04/ and installed Python 3.8 with `apt` from the deadsnakes PPA. But I am still not able to create a Python 3.8 virtual environment. If I do `virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.8`, I got this:

```
user@host:~$ virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3.8 venv
RuntimeError: failed to query /usr/bin/python3.8 with code 1 err: 'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/virtualenv/discovery/py_info.py", line 16, in <module>\n    from distutils import dist\nImportError: cannot import name \'dist\' from \'distutils\' (/usr/lib/python3.8/distutils/__init__.py)\n'
```

Answer (score 14):

I noticed that the [deadsnakes ppa](https://launchpad.net/%7Edeadsnakes/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) has instructions that include this:

- `python#.#-venv`: provides the standard library `venv` module

So, I believe you need to make sure to `apt install python3.8-venv`. Then the following will work:

```sh
python3.8 -m venv venv_dir
```

If you really want to use `virtualenv` and not just the native `venv`, then you could install it, but you would first need `pip`. So the process would look something like this:

```sh
python3.8 -m ensurepip
python3.8 -m pip install virtualenv
python3.8 -m virtualenv venv_dir
```

I hope this helps! In case you want to read (and review/critique, as I would welcome it) I have written a [summary of several Python virtual environment tools](https://dev.to/bowmanjd/python-tools-for-managing-virtual-environments-3bko) you may find helpful. Feel free to tell me how I can make it better.

Answer (score 3):

I have Ubuntu 20.04lts, and I believe that everyone will be benefited from this solution. I wanted to create a virtual environment for Python 3.8 to use in Pycharm.
First-

```
sudo apt install python3.8-venv
```

then-

```
/usr/bin/python3.8 -m venv virtualenv_directory/
```

This will make the virtual environment.
Then follow the link to use in PyCharm -
[link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/creating-virtual-environment.html#python_create_virtual_env)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the built-in [`venv` module](https://docs.python.org/library/venv.html#module-venv) instead of `virtualenv`:

```
/usr/bin/python3.8 -m venv virtualenv_directory/
```

`venv` has been included with Python since version 3.3.

Comment: I got an error running it.

`
user@host:~$ /usr/bin/python3.8 -m venv virtualenv_directory
Error: Command '['/home/user/virtualenv_directory/bin/python3.8', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
`

Comment: @fhcat, do you have internet access on this machine?

Answer (score 0):

The deadsnakes repo is no longer available for Ubuntu 16.04. [See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72227238/1195050) how to install a recent python version via pyenv.